# Can inline function be called within the same header c++ file?

Tags: c++, inline

See the following class

```
class wdt
{
   public:
      inline static constexpr uint32_t wdtGetTimeoutValue( uint32_t xTimeInNs )
      {
         return (wdt_get_timeout_value((xTimeInNs*1000),BOARD_FREQ_SLCK_XTAL));
      }

   private:
     static constexpr const uint32_t mMsWdtTimeout = wdtGetTimeoutValue(mMsTaskInterval);

}
```

and this is `wdt_get_timeout_value()` which will be called.

```
uint32_t wdt_get_timeout_value(uint32_t ul_us, uint32_t ul_sclk)
{
      uint32_t max, min;

      min = WDT_SLCK_DIV * 1000000 / ul_sclk;
      max = min * WDT_MAX_VALUE;

      if ((ul_us < min) || (ul_us > max)) {
        return WDT_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
      }

      return WDT_MR_WDV(ul_us / min);
 }
```

I got the following errors:

```
error: 'static constexpr uint32_t Platform::Watchdog::wdtGetTimeoutValue(uint32_t)' called in a constant expression before its definition is complete
 static constexpr const uint32_t mMsWdtTimeout = wdtGetTimeoutValue(mMsTaskInterval);
```

How can I fix the error? Thx!

Comment: Show some [MCVE] please. We don't know what is `wdt_get_timeout_value`, so **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: Your class is considered incomplete until the closing brace. You cannot use a member function of an incomplete class for a `static constexpr` member, even if it's the same class.

Comment: Your error does not match the code in your post.  Please make a [mcve] with an error that comes from it

Comment: There is no need to post a such complex example to show what your intention is. So please do not copy your real world code unchanged into SO. We also need time to read it. More people will help if your question is clear and your reduced example is simple to understand and can be compiled on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

1) No, you can't use a member function for a constexpr until the class definition is completed.

2) If you call a method from a constexpr member function, the called function must also be constexpr. In your case `wdt_get_timeout_value` must be constexpr also.

Maybe you can define a base class which contains your methods which will be called from your derived class with constexpr.

see example:

```
constexpr int ext( int i)
{
    return i+2;
}

class Base
{
    protected:
    static constexpr int f( int i) { return ext(i)*2; }
};

class A: public Base
{
    public:
    static constexpr int val = 9;
    static constexpr int var = f( val );
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << A::var << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: yes, u r right! I want to initialize const value `var`, however, `wdt_get_timeout_value()` does not return const value and cannot be changed coz it is from library.

Comment: @Lei: And if the answer is correct for you, why you don't accept it and/or up vote? That you can't made your external func constexpr is not a fault of my answer :-) Here in SO we pay by votes! And signing an answer as accepted help others to know it is helpful and correct!